# Binary Search Tree implementation - Finding Siblings from a given node is not working properly

Tags: c++, debugging, binary-search-tree, siblings

I'm building a program based on binary search trees. I am having problems with finding the siblings. Whenever the tree already has a sibling it works perfectly, no problem at all. But, if it doesn't have a sibling it crashes and doesn't say the message "No tiene hermanos" which means it doesn't have brothers.

Terminology:
izq = left,der = right ,nodo = node, hermano = sibling

I don't get why it doesn't work properly, I tried being general, being specific, my capabilities are not enough. 
I tried including the if statements in, out, changing the code with a parent node, changing the order of the ifs. I changed the function into a void, changed the returns, returned a general message, no return on the left and right move, idk.

```
 bool Hermanos (Nodo *arbol, int n) {
     if (arbol == NULL){
         return false;
     }
     else if ((arbol->der->dato == n) || (arbol->izq->dato == n )) {
         if ( arbol->der->dato == n && arbol->izq != NULL){
             cout<<arbol->izq->dato;
         }
         else if (arbol->izq->dato == n && arbol->der != NULL){
             cout<<arbol->der->dato;
         }
         else if ((arbol->izq == NULL) || (arbol->der == NULL)){
             cout<<"No tiene hermanos";
         }
         return true;
      }
      else if (n < arbol -> dato) {
          return Hermanos(arbol->izq, n);
      }
      else {
          return Hermanos(arbol->der, n);
      }
  }
```

Let's say I have 2 nodes, 5 and 20, being 20 the right children. If I look up for 20 it should say "It doesn't have a sibling."

Answer (score 1):

The main `if` that checks the child nodes for `n` can dereference NULL pointers, if either the right or left nodes are missing.

With your example data, once you find a right node that has `n`, your first if within that block will be true if that node is a right child AND the parent node (`arbol`) has a left child.  If that is not the case, we check the next if, and that is where the problem is.  If there is no left child, the `arbol->izq->dato` will dereference a NULL pointer.

This can easily be seen because you dereference `arbol->izq->data`, then check `arbol->izq` for NULL *after* checking the data at the (potentially nonexistent) node.

So you have several places where you can dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it still  not working perfectly when I run it, but when I debug it it works better, it still throws me some errors I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

I changed up the code, with the help of your comment.

```
else if ((arbol->der->dato == n) || (arbol->izq->dato == n )){

//ENCONTRO ARBOL DERECHO
    if( arbol -> der -> dato == n){
        if( arbol -> izq != NULL){
        cout<< arbol->izq->dato;
        }
        else{
        cout<<"No tiene hermano izquierdo";
        }
    }

//ENCONTRO ARBOL IZQUIERDO
    else if( arbol -> izq -> dato == n){
        if( arbol -> der != NULL){
        cout<< arbol->der->dato;
        }
        else{
        cout<<"No tiene hermano derecho";
        }
    }
```

I still shows some errores but I think the syntax is better here.

Comment: I got a new version of my code where it tells if they don't have siblings correctly for  the 1st and the 2nd lvl of the tree. But, whenever I do it with further levels it tells they have brothers.

Answer (score 0):

I changed up the code, with the help of your comment. Now, it is a Node function where it returns a node and in another function I ask if it is NULL or not. What it is supposed to do is return NULL if either one of the left or right node is NULL.

```
Nodo* Hermanos (Nodo *arbol, int n){
if (arbol == NULL){
    return NULL;
}

else if ((arbol->der !=NULL) && (arbol->izq !=NULL )){

//ENCONTRO ARBOL DERECHO
    if( arbol -> der -> dato == n)
        return arbol->izq;

//ENCONTRO ARBOL IZQUIERDO
    else if( arbol -> izq -> dato == n)
        return arbol->der;

        }

    else if (n < arbol -> dato){
        return Hermanos(arbol->izq, n);
    }

    else if ( n > arbol ->dato){
        return Hermanos(arbol->der, n);
    }

    else /*if ( arbol -> der == NULL || arbol -> izq == NULL) */
    return NULL;

 }
```

It work perfectly for the root and the 1st level of the tree, but whenever there is no sibling node, on further levels, it reads as if there is one.

Second Function

```
        gotoxy(32,26);
        cout<<"Hermano: ";

        b = Hermanos(arbol,num);
        if(b == NULL)
          cout<<"No tiene hermano";

        else
        cout<<b<<endl;
```